# JDT can't handle multiline String?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

EDIT: It seems like the code can't compile... 
I found where is the error in the code. 
In fact, my test was not well written.
... Thanks for your help

I'm trying to parse some java code with the jdt parser but I have a problem with parsing multiline string.
Example:

```java
import com.Label;

public class OnlyMulitlineInstantiation {

    public void multiLine() {
        Label label = new Label(                "


                        ");
    }
}
```

In this example, the AST has the class, the method, but the method is empty.
However in this one:

```java
import com.Label;

public class OnlyMulitlineInstantiation {

    public void multiLine() {
        Label label = new Label(                ""+


                        ""        );
    }
}
```

The method is not empty (in the produced AST).
Note that I have just added the **+**.

Anyone can reproduce that? Should I add an option?

EDIT: It seems like the code can't compile... I'm looking for further information

Comment: AFAIK Java itself does not yet support multiline strings.

Comment: @Marvin Java 13 has 'text blocks' which are multi-line but have a different syntax.

Comment: I thought too. But I can find such kind of executed code in my company projects.

Comment: I don't know how this compiles for your company, but for me it doesn't. Maybe you should dig into that.

Comment: This is definitely not valid Java - see the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) - _It is a compile-time error for a line terminator to appear after the opening " and before the closing matching "_

Comment: So just use `"   \n"+"    \n"`